# How to export 3d standalone [v3.0]

Tags: export

Is blender able to export to any kind of standalone 3D files or to an executable other than videos

I need to generate something like a game (in fact: an interactive educational content)

Need to export for both linux and windows

I tried UPBGE but I don't think I understood how it differs from original blender, and blender game engine has gone

Also the exported format should be openGL version independent - users are mostly students, softwere and hardwere should be flexible and easy for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Check the File menu, Export sub menu. Blender comes with about eight formats already enabled as I remember, and there are some disabled but included add-ons for more that you can enable in Edit -> Preferences -> Add-ons, and then there are add-ons all over the Internet for even more I/O formats, including Source engine models with blender Source tools.

Comment: could any of them be executed by itself and works as a 3D rendered view so students could work around the model - I need to provide standalone files for multible platforms that could be similar to this android app: [Cell World](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.VIEW.CellWorld&hl=en&gl=US)

Comment: @Abd-ElazizSharaf That would be a bundling of a file and a 3D Viewer to open it. That is not an export format for a model, that’s exporting an executable. You can do that with UpBGE. But, why not just export something like an OBJ and use Microsoft 3D Viewer to open it?

Comment: I'm using linux - and so do some of my studendts - others may use mac - most of engines have many appilities but with a good docs for how to work with program and compine it with other software - and less word on how to export for end user - I didn't findout how to export with upbge and didn't find any tuturial for that - seems like blender only love blender users - and not every student will have the ability to run it - even if so most would run an **legacy** version 2.79... let's retype my question in other words @TheLabCat is there any guide of how to do exports for end user in blender

Comment: @Abd-ElazizSharaf Once again, what you are asking for is not a 3-D model export format, but an executable. What’s more, you’re asking for an executable that is cross platform compatible, so basically your only option is a jar file, which blender most definitely cannot export.

Comment: no problem if I built many files one for each system if that is possible - I just want the scene to live as a 3D model outside of any program - what is the end format that blender could build for me if jar is not an option

Comment: if you know you're going to use 2.79 maybe you can try blend4web, and use a web browser to navigate your models...

Comment: @Abd-ElazizSharaf You can’t make the models viewable outside of any program. You can include a little program for each model to open it, and rely on the operating system programs on each computer to run that, but you can’t view a model without any instructions for how to view it for the computer. I still think your best option is to just have your students install model viewing software (such as Blender, since it’s cross-platform), and then give them the 3-D model to look at.

Comment: @alambre I reelly tried B4W however rendering with B4W makes materials act crazy 
(ex: eye material rendered as it's inside ont out and so did many things) and developers told me that development stoped, it's a scientific 3D models, everything should run as best as I could, and I wont find further enhancement

Comment: @TheLabCat may be but blender is used to generate games cross platform, could blender by itself create basic 3D games so I could export 3D views in a game, if so I think I played around wrong tutorials so I would love if someone guide me for a good one

Comment: @Abd-ElazizSharaf I’ve already answered yes to that. UpBGE is the latest implementation of Blender that has a game engine, but if you want to go official, switch back to 2.79. If your question is now how to export an executable from game engine Blender, ask that separately.

Comment: I'm looking for previous questions first, then go on asking, thanks for your time a lot